# Удалить неправильно набранный пароль для команды sudo

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Я выполняю в терминале некоторую команду от имени суперпользователя с помощью sudo, примерно так:

```
sudo ...
```

Мне предлагают ввести пароль, я ввожу несколько первых символов пароля и понимаю, что ошибся в одном из символов. Я хочу удалить пароль и ввести его заново. Какой наиболее удобный способ сделать это?

Вижу два варианта:

- нажимать <kbd>Backspace</kbd> достаточное число раз, чтобы быть уверенным, что удалились все символы пароля (введённые символы пароля не показываются, поэтому нельзя однозначно сказать, сколько сейчас введено символов)
- нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>, увидеть, что пароль неправильный, подождать некоторое время, пока не отобразится новое предложение ввести пароль.

Видно, что оба варианта не очень удобны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

популярными оболочками отлично воспринимается в такой ситуации ввод <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

---

из справки (`man bash`, оно же в `man readline`, т.к. *bash* использует именно библиотеку *readline* для обработки ввода):

> **unix-line-discard (C-u)**
>   Kill backward from point to the beginning of  the  line.   The
>                 killed text is saved on the kill-ring.

вольный перевод:

> удалить текст с текущей позиции до начала строки. удаляемый текст сохраняется в *kill-ring*.

аналогичные описания, по идее, можно встретить и в справках по другим популярным оболочкам.

Comment: добавил бы, что проверить все активные сочетания  в bash можно: bind -P